# Competitive coding template in vim macro

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, macro, filetype-c++

I want to have a vim register that pastes :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define 1e9 + 7
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

return 0;}
```

But when I write this in .vimrc ahead of

```
let @a = '...
```

I have write it all in a single line. How do I specify the newlines after each include directive.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I think it may be a "better" solution.

```
nnoremap cct :-1read $HOME/.vim/cct.c<CR>6ji<Tab>
```

Typing in <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> in Normal mode will paste in the contents from
`$HOME/.vim/cct.c`, which would contain the template you want. Then, `6ji<Tab>` moves
you to inside the `main` function, puts you in Insert mode and adds an indent to start you off.

You can of course change the shortcut to your leader key plus something or anything else really. I think this is probably better and more easily updated than putting the whole template directly in your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming (because you used the [[macro]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macro) tag) that you want to set the `"a` register to be a macro, that, when played back, inserts the provided lines.

One way to do that is the following:

```
let @a = "o"
      \. "#include <iostream>\r"
      \. "#include <string>\r"
      \. "#define 1e9 + 7\r"
      \. "typedef long long ll;\r"
      \. "using namespace std;\r"
      \. "int main(int argc, char ** argv){\r"
      \. "\r"
      \. "return 0;}\<Esc>"
```

The `\` line continuations and `.` concatenations aren't strictly necessary. You could include the whole lot in a single string, but this will look neater in your `.vimrc`.

I don't think I'd actually use this myself, though. It would be cleaner to set up a mapping or command to do this, to use [Kevin's solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15181/343), or to look into the several [snippet plugins](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vim+snippet) that provide this feature in a more flexible way.

If you actually just want the register to contain the text so that you can `put` it with commands such as `"ap`, you need to alter the code slightly:

```
let @a = "#include <iostream>\n"
      \. "#include <string>\n"
      \. "#define 1e9 + 7\n"
      \. "typedef long long ll;\n"
      \. "using namespace std;\n"
      \. "int main(int argc, char ** argv){\n"
      \. "\n"
      \. "return 0;}"
```